# Value adding with CHOICE in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm not sure how something like this is titled or called, so not sure how to research it

My goal is adding a word multiple times

Lets say I want to add more `amount` to `filename.txt` lets say I want 10 more added it would be an append to the file

```
New folder 1\filename.txt
    --"Code": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"Code": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"Code": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
    --"amount": 0,
```

I have an append script, and with this script I can append the `amount` many times, and just run the script, but I would like a `variable` type of script

```
@echo off

SET /P variable=[EnterValue]

FOR %%i IN (All_Merged_Files.txt) do (
     >" %%i.tmp" echo     "amount",
    >>"%%i.tmp" type "%%i"
    del "%%i"
    ren "%%i.tmp" "%%~nxi"
)
```

Here is another go at my script

```
@echo off
 
 FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ("3Ready\*.txt") DO call :label "%%q"
goto :eof

:Label
set "FILE=%~1"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO (
     >"%~1.tmp" echo     "Pending",
    >>"%~1.tmp" type "%~1"
    del "%~1"
    ren "%~1.tmp" "%%~nx%~1"
)
```

I managed to make this almost make the script below work

```
    @echo off
     
     FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ("3Ready\*.txt") DO call :label "%%q"
    goto :eof
    
    :Label
    set "FILE=%~1"
    FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO >>"%~1.tmp" echo     "Pending",
```

this script above gave me this result it copied the file and make a new file with the word "pending"

```
My tester.txt
 the content inside
---word
---word

The results
My tester.txt
 the content inside
"Pending",
"Pending",
"Pending",
"Pending",
"Pending",
"Pending",
"Pending",
"Pending",
"Pending",
```

Comment: The `choice` command utility, `choice.exe`, is not really of any use to you for this because it accepts only single key entry according to those listed in the `/C` option. What you'll need is the `Set` command with its `/P` option instead. Please note however that the `Set /P` prompt accepts nothing or absolutely anything as input. It is very important therefore that you include code to validate that the input is one or more digits before attempting to use that input.

Comment: @Compo the `/p/ helped me a lot Thank you with the adding the value to amount, now going to see if I can add it to append - might need your help with that one I will tag you if I do

Comment: OK question how do I control to ask me the mount for each amount, like if I I want `amount 500, amount 700, amount 300` etc - instead of all amounts being same value

Comment: @Compo - I've tried different ways to add the `set /p` to my script with no luck